# FuelPHP installation with composer update requesting a Github OAuth token

Tags: php, github, composer-php, fuelphp

I downloaded fuelphp 1.7.3 from [its website](http://fuelphp.com/). When I run `composer update`, I'm requested to enter a token. What token I will have to provide?

> $ composer update
>   Loading composer repositories with package information
>
> Could not fetch https://api.github.com/repos/fuel/docs, please create
>   a GitHub O Auth token to go over the API rate limit
>   Head to https://github.com/settings/tokens/new?scopes=repo&description=Composer+
>   on+Sithu+2015-06-25+1050
>   to retrieve a token. It will be stored in "C:/Users/Singtech/AppData/Roaming/Com poser/auth.json" for future use by Composer.
>   Token (hidden):

Answer (score 2):

As others said this has nothing to do with FuelPHP itself, but there is a valid point though that users without Github account should still be able to use FuelPHP.

As others also pointed, this error is caused by the [Github API rate limit](https://developer.github.com/v3/#rate-limiting), which is 50/hour AFAIK.

What you can do (if you have a Github account) is generating an API key and configuring composer to use it as written [here](http://nschoenmaker.nl/2013/02/composer-api-limit-at-github/)

If you don't have a Github account, it is very unlikely you can use composer with public repositories. In this case I suggest using the provided ZIP file from our [homepage](http://fuelphp.com/).

If you need an updated version of any dependencies, download the dependency ZIP from Github and configure a custom repository for that package as written [here](https://getcomposer.org/doc/05-repositories.md)

Answer (score 1):

1. Use the official Zip file.
2. Wait until GitHub API limits reset (60 hits/one hour).

Answer (score 1):

- Login to your GitHub account
- Go to https://github.com/settings/tokens
- Create a token
- In "C:/Users/Singtech/AppData/Roaming/Com poser/auth.json" put:

> ```
> {
>   "config": {
>     "github-oauth": {
>       "github.com": "YOUR_TOKEN"
>     }
>   }
> }
> ```

Answer (score 0):

If you have a github account, use it,

Comment: What if I have no github account? Those who are going to use FuelPHP should not be expected to have github account. I don't understand why.

Comment: This is not actually a fuelphp related thing, github puts limits on the API they provide (which composer uses) for non-authenticated users. The only way to get around this is to get a github account or stop using composer.